# Browsing Directory Using ui and QTreeWidget with qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, directory-listing

I have created a ui with QT designer.

In that ui i use one pushbutton for browse directories,and one lineedit for select dir path text to show, and another pushbuton for ok, these 3 widgets and one treewidget are placed on a groupbox horizontally.

What I would want to know is if i browse and click ok button then i want to display the treeview to that path on the ui

my test1.h file contains

```
#ifndef LINEEDIT_H
#define LINEEDIT_H

#include <QtGui>
#include "ui_line1.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Ui;

class line : public QMainWindow 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    line(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QTreeWidget(parent);

    void viewer(QTreeWidgetItem* item,QString filePath);

private:
    Ui::lineedit ui;
     QDirModel *model;
    public slots:
        void browse();
        void  treeview();
    void showDirectory(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int /*column*/);

};
#endif // LINEEDIT_H
```

my test1.cpp  file contains

```
#include "test1.h"
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<QWidget>
#include<QTreeWidgetItem>
line::line(QWidget* parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.browse, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(browse()));
    connect(ui.ok, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(treeview()));
    connect(this , SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)),this,SLOT(showDirectory(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)));
}   
void line::browse()
{   
    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
        "/home",QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly   | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    ui.lineEdit->setText(dir);  
}
void line::treeview()
{   


    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget();
    line  *tree = new line (centralWidget);
    tree->setFixedSize(395,395);
    QTreeWidgetItem* headerItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    headerItem->setText(0,QString("File Name"));
    headerItem->setText(1,QString("Size (Bytes)"));
    headerItem->setText(2,QString("Path"));
    ui.treeWidget->setHeaderItem(headerItem);
     ui.treeWidget->setColumnCount(2);
    //ui.treeView->
    //setHeaderItem(headerItem);
    QString strdir=ui.lineEdit->text();
    QDir* rootDir = new QDir(strdir);
    QFileInfoList filesList = rootDir->entryInfoList();
    foreach(QFileInfo fileInfo, filesList)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        item->setText(0,fileInfo.fileName());
        if(fileInfo.isFile())
        {  
            item->setText(1,QString::number(fileInfo.size()));
            item->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("file.jpg")));
        }
        if(fileInfo.isDir())
        {
            item->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("folder.jpg")));
            viewer(item,fileInfo.filePath());
        } 
        item->setText(2,fileInfo.filePath());
        ui.treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(item);     
    }
    QPalette* palette = new QPalette();
    palette->setColor(QPalette::Base,Qt::red);  
    ui.treeWidget->setPalette(*(palette));
    /*window->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);*/
    /*ui.treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(centralWidget);*/
    /*window->show();*/
    return treeview();
}
void line::viewer(QTreeWidgetItem* item,QString filePath)
{
    QDir* rootDir = new QDir(filePath);
    QFileInfoList filesList = rootDir->entryInfoList();   
    foreach(QFileInfo fileInfo, filesList)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* child = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        child->setText(0,fileInfo.fileName());
        if(fileInfo.isFile())
        {  
            child->setText(1,QString::number(fileInfo.size()));
        }
        if(fileInfo.isDir())
        {
            child->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("folder.jpg")));
            child->setText(2,fileInfo.filePath());
        }  
        item->addChild(child);
    }
}
void line::showDirectory(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int )
{
    QDir* rootDir = new QDir(item->text(2));
    QFileInfoList filesList = rootDir->entryInfoList();   
    foreach(QFileInfo fileInfo, filesList)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* child = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        child->setText(0,fileInfo.fileName());    
        if(fileInfo.isFile())
        {  
            child->setText(1,QString::number(fileInfo.size()));
            child->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("file.jpg")));
        }
        if(fileInfo.isDir())
        {
            child->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("folder.jpg")));
            child->setText(2,fileInfo.filePath());
        } 
        item->addChild(child);
        /*resizeColumnToContents(0);*/
    }
}
```

main.cpp  contains

```
#include "test1.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    line w;
    w.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

am not getting output,  while  am checking on the debug points each and every thing fine but not getting the output on the ui treewidget

Is this possible, please help me  where can i modify my  code.

Thanks all.

Comment: This might help: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-itemviews-dirview-example.html

Comment: But i want to interfere ui  to browse the path , from that path i want to show a treeview, please give me a simple example how can i get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test1.cppfile:

```
#include "test1.h"
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<QWidget>
#include<QTreeWidgetItem>
line::line(QWidget* parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.browse, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(browse()));
    connect(ui.ok, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(treeview()));
    connect(this , SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)),this,SLOT(showDirectory(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)));
}   
void line::browse()
{   
    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
        "/home",QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly   | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    ui.lineEdit->setText(dir);  
}
void line::treeview()
{   
    QString strdir=ui.lineEdit->text();
    QDir* rootDir = new QDir(strdir);
    QFileInfoList filesList = rootDir->entryInfoList();
    /*QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem();*/
 ui.treeWidget->setColumnCount(1);
 QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> items;
 foreach(QFileInfo fileInfo, filesList)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        item->setText(0,fileInfo.fileName());
        if(fileInfo.isFile())
        {  
            item->setText(1,QString::number(fileInfo.size()));
            item->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("file.jpg")));
            /*treeItem->setCurrentItem(item);*/
        }
        if(fileInfo.isDir())
        {
            item->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("folder.jpg")));
            viewer(item,fileInfo.filePath());
        } 
        item->setText(2,fileInfo.filePath());
        ui.treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(item);   
        /* ui.treeWidget->insertTopLevelItems(0, item);*/
     items.append(new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList(QString("item: %1"))));
 ui.treeWidget->insertTopLevelItems(0, items);
 }
}
 void line::viewer(QTreeWidgetItem* item,QString filePath)
 {
    QDir* rootDir = new QDir(filePath);
    QFileInfoList filesList = rootDir->entryInfoList();   
    foreach(QFileInfo fileInfo, filesList)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* child = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        child->setText(0,fileInfo.fileName());
        if(fileInfo.isFile())
        {  
            child->setText(1,QString::number(fileInfo.size()));
        }
        if(fileInfo.isDir())
        {
            child->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("folder.jpg")));
            child->setText(2,fileInfo.filePath());
        }  
        item->addChild(child);
        ui.treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(item);
    }
 }
 void line::showDirectory(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int )
 {
    QDir* rootDir = new QDir(item->text(2));
    QFileInfoList filesList = rootDir->entryInfoList();   
    foreach(QFileInfo fileInfo, filesList)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* child = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        child->setText(0,fileInfo.fileName());    
        if(fileInfo.isFile())
        {  
            child->setText(1,QString::number(fileInfo.size()));
            child->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("file.jpg")));
        }
        if(fileInfo.isDir())
        {
            child->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("folder.jpg")));
            child->setText(2,fileInfo.filePath());
        } 
        item->addChild(child);
        ui.treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(item);
        /*resizeColumnToContents(0);*/
    }


 }
```

test1.h file:

```
#ifndef LINEEDIT_H
#define LINEEDIT_H

#include <QtGui>
#include "ui_line1.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Ui;

class line : public QMainWindow 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    line(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QTreeWidget(parent);

    void viewer(QTreeWidgetItem* item,QString filePath);

private:
    Ui::lineedit ui;
     QDirModel *model;
    public slots:
        void browse();
        void  treeview();
    void showDirectory(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int /*column*/);

};
#endif // LINEEDIT_H
```

main.cpp file:

```
#include "test1.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    line w;
    w.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```